# Incrementar quantidade de veículos com trigger

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, trigger

Tenho a tabela `pessoa` que tem a coluna `qtd_veiculos`, toda vez que eu der um `insert` com um novo veiculo, que tenha o CPF `foreign_key` igual ao de alguma pessoa da tabela `pessoa`, essa coluna deve ser incrementada em 1, não estou chegando a lugar nenhum para fazer isso.

Tentativa 1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION incrementa_qtd_veiculos() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE pessoa SET qtd_veiculos = qtd_veiculos+1 WHERE cpf = new.veiculo.cpf_dono;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Tentativa 2:

```
CREATE TRIGGER incr_qtd_veiculos AFTER
INSERT ON pessoa
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE incrementa_qtd_veiculos();
```

P.S.: O banco de dados contém informações referente a monitoramento de veículos.

Comment: Dei uma remasterizada na sua pergunta para ter mais aceitação :)

Comment: Não seria AFTER INSERT ON veiculo?

Comment: Não seria mais prático você dar um COUNT de veículos para aquele CPF cada vez que quisesse tal informação?